# CSV import thousands of rows

Tags: php, csv, php-7

I have multiple csv feeds to read with php 7.3.

When i have less than 500 lines (perhaps 1000) it works fine but with more i have

> 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
> exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)

I read a lot of things about this common error

In php.ini, if I added

```
memory_limit=1024M
```

It is similar if I change it to -1.

Data comes from an api

You could see below the 4 main functions called

The error provides from the last (function parse - `$lines[$index] = str_getcsv($line);`)

Instead of getting the full file into a variable, i parse it for newlines and then do str_getcsv on each array element.

```
public function getProducts(Advertiser $advertiser): ProductCollection
{
    $response = $this->getResponse($advertiser->getFeedUrl());
    $content = gzdecode($response);

    $products = $this->csvParser->parseProducts($content);

    return $products;
}

private function getResponse(string $url): string
{
    $cacheKey = sprintf('%s-%s',
        static::CACHE_PREFIX,
        md5($url)
    );

    if ($this->cache->has($cacheKey)) {
        return $this->cache->get($cacheKey);
    }

    $response = $this->client->request(static::REQUEST_METHOD, $url);
    $body     = (string) $response->getBody();

    $this->cache->set($cacheKey, $body);

    return $body;
}

public function parseProducts(string $csvContent): ProductCollection
{
    $lines = $this->parse($csvContent);
    $keys = array_shift($lines);

    return new ProductCollection($keys, $lines);
}


private function parse(string $content): array
{
    $lines = str_getcsv($content, PHP_EOL);

    foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {
        $lines[$index] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    return $lines;
}
```

So, i think it's due to parse functon but i don't know what to do

Comment: You cannot expect to be able to read data of arbitrary length into memory. No matter what memory limit you set (and you should set one...) it has to run out and some given length of the input data. Instead you need to read the data in chunks and process those, so that your code can free the memory used for each chunk before reading the next chunk. That way your memory footprint stays the same, no matter how big the volume of the data gets.

Comment: Here this means that you should only read single lines into memory and process those one by one instead of reading the whole file and then slitting it.

Comment: @arkascha yes, but i don't know how to do that. I try with my parse function.